# Entity framework model class navigation property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a class, `Rate` which can have two locations; `LocationTo` and `LocationFrom`. Locations should be a drop-down list on the page.

My models look like like this:

```
public class Rate
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RateName { get; set; }
    public int LocationToId { get; set; }
    public int LocationFromId { get; set; }
    public virtual Location LocationTo { get; set; }
    public virtual Location LocationFrom { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Rate> Rates { get; set; }
}
```

Am I thinking correct here?

---

is this right ohlin? what does public virtual Location LocationTo { get; set; } do?

```
   public class Location
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("LocationToId")]
    public virtual ICollection<Rate> ToRates { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("LocationFromId")]
    public virtual ICollection<Rate> FromRates { get; set; }
}
public class Rate
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RateName { get; set; }
    public int LocationToId { get; set; }
    public int? LocationFromId { get; set; }
    public virtual Location LocationTo { get; set; }
    public virtual Location LocationFrom { get; set; }
}
public class dc : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Location> Locations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Rate> Rates { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Did you try this before posting? Is there something not working as you would expect?

Comment: I'm not sure you need `public virtual ICollection<Rate> Rates { get; set; }` as it looks like a one way association **from** `Rate`.

Comment: I have tried it, problem is how to bind the rates locations to dropdownlists and how to update a rate and fill the navigation properties in an mvc applicaton

Comment: So the problem has nothing to do with Entity Framework? What kind of web framework are you using?

Comment: ah ok. im using asp.net mvc

Comment: @TomasBredh I think you should update your question since the problem really isn't about the entities themselves, but how to update them, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem with your model is that you have two Location references for each Rate and you need to help EF out a little by adding some attributes. The default name for a foreign id in the Rate class should be LocationId, but you have two references and thus need to give them separate names. Nothing wrong with that...

But you need to to change a little in the Location model:

```
public class Location
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("LocationToId")]
    public virtual ICollection<Rate> ToRates { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("LocationFromId")]
    public virtual ICollection<Rate> FromRates { get; set; }
}
```

By adding the **InverseProperty** attribute EF can find it's way from Location to Rate

**Edit: Example of drop down list**

Ok, the question changed a little :-) To add drop down lists you can write in this way.

```
@model Rate
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.LocationFromId, ((IEnumerable<Location>)ViewBag.PossibleLocations).Select(option => new SelectListItem {
    Text = Html.DisplayTextFor(_ => option).ToString(), 
    Value = option.Id.ToString(),
    Selected = (Model != null) && (option.Id == Model.LocationFromId)
}), "Choose...")
```

What you need to do to make this work is to create a variable named PossibleLocations in the ViewBag in the Controller before you pass on to the View.

Comment: I will test this Ohlin and get back to you asap!

Comment: ok when I run this I'll get an error sayin "Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints"

Comment: That's because you have two links to Location. Define one of them `int?` instead of `int` and it should work better.

Comment: I can also mention that the error message you got is from SQL Server and relates to the fact that one object is linked to two different objects in one other table. I get that error quite often when I make a solution like yours and by writing `public int? LocationFromId { get; set; }` you fix the problem. What you basically do is telling that the id is "optional" but in your code you can later on make sure that it's always there. This is just a "fix" to make sure SQL Server approves your model.